# What IDEs are available for jRuby?

Tags: ruby, ide, jruby

I've done some googling and there seems to be a scarcity of IDEs for jRuby.
I've read about TextMate and Sublime, but they don't provide debugging or code completion.

Can someone make a suggestion (or is this technology still in its infancy)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an "IDE for JRuby"? In what way does an IDE for JRuby differ from an IDE for Ruby? If you want an IDE for Ruby, there are plenty of options: Eclipse, NetBeans, VisualStudio, IntelliJ come to mind.

Comment: JRuby - as in allows you to have a Project, to have integrated compilation and debugging with Code Completion.

Comment: Those are all standard features of a Ruby IDE. But you don't ask for a Ruby IDE, you ask *specifically* about a JRuby IDE, and I am wondering what the difference is between a Ruby IDE and a JRuby IDE. Like I said, finding a Ruby IDE is trivial, there are dozens of them.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I was kind of looking for an IDE that would be an almost out of the box solution for Ruby/jRuby. An if there was to be a difference for jRuby, it would be being able to build and deploy packages for remote servers and including the dependencies, without me needing to recompile or build them on the remote server.

Comment: @DaneBalia What is "integrated compilation" in an interpreted language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options; I prefer [JetBrains' IntelliJ (RubyMine)](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/).

[Aptana has an Eclipse plugin](http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails). [NetBeans used to have official support](http://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html), not sure what the [current state](http://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html) is.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Tried IntelliJ and it sucks a bit. Hoping we might see something in the future.

Comment: Sucks how?! It's far and away the best IDE on the market, although recent Eclipse has made strides. I'm not really familiar with NetBeans. But to say it sucks after 20 minutes is just funny.

Comment: The Ruby NetBeans plugin is now maintained by Tom Enebo and other Ruby community members. Unfortunately it looks like it's only supported through 7.1 for now. http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails

Comment: apologies I was wrong - RubyMine is without a doubt a great IDE. It has support for gems and integrates with "Warbler".